# SELECT MAX() function in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to figure out a problem I'm having with a `SELECT MAX()` command. I want to gather the highest value in the 'BidAmount' column, but I only want selected entries to be scanned for the highest value.

For example, I want the highest 'BidAmount' to be returned where another column 'UserID' = 6.  I want to know the highest 'BidAmount' for a specific customer (so the column 'UserID' will equal '6').

I tried using this:

```
SELECT MAX(`BidAmount`) FROM `requests` WHERE `UserID` = 6
```

But it doesn't work. If the above SQL code should work, it might be a problem with my PHP. What shall I do?

Comment: SQL is fine. Can you share the expected and actual result along with the test data that you are trying this query on?

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement for the `REQUESTS` table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SELECT MAX(BidAmount) FROM requests WHERE UserID = 6 **GROUP BY UserID**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

The sql seems fine, tested just to be sure, so I see 3 possible problems: 
 - you mistype one of the column names or the table name 
 - UserID is not number 
 - the problem is in your app code 
 
You can try to execute the query in a phpmyadmin or toad for mysql, to see the error message if there is...

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is fine. What do you mean by *doesn't work*? Please show us sample data, and actual vs. expected output from your query.

**Update**

It sounds like you may have an incorrect data type for BidAmount and are getting a non-numeric sort. Can you tell us what that data type is?

Comment: If I use the WHERE clause, it returns nothing. If I remove the WHERE clause, it'll return '5' even though the highest value is '55'.

Comment: @Jamie you need to cast it as int.

Comment: @Jamie: see my update above. Providing schema and sample data would be helpful.